# Connection between Analytic and harmonic

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, harmonic-functions, analytic-functions

I know that every analytic function $f(z)$ is harmonic .

Is it true or false that every harmonic function $f(z)$ is analytic.

I cannot think of a counter example. So am i right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x+iy)=x$ is harmonic but not analytic.